# How can i optimize the recursion in the plan?

Tags: java, swing, recursion

i would like to wander every land pixel by pixel, but I encounter stackoverflow in bigger countries(Russia,France).How can I optimize recursion?

```
public class Hajra extends JFrame {

    public int [] xxx={-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0};
    public int [] yyy={-1,0,1,1,1,0,1,-1};
    public BufferedImage    img;
     public long a,b; 
     public boolean ok = false;
     public int x,y;
    Hajra(){
         setBounds(50,50,770,609);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            setResizable(false);
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Isti/workspace/preprocess/backgroud.jpg")));

             try{
                    img=ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Isti/workspace/preprocess/backgroud.jpg"));
                    } catch (IOException t) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        }

         this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                 x = e.getX();
                 y = e.getY();
                a = img.getRGB(x, y);
                if(Math.abs(a)<600000){
                bejar(x+15,y+5);}
                File f = new File("MyFileee2.png");
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", f);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
     }

     void bejar ( int ujx , int ujy){

             for(int i=0;i<8;i++){   
                ///System.out.println(  "---"+ ujx + "  " + ujy+   " \n");
                 if(Math.abs(Math.abs(a)-Math.abs(img.getRGB(ujx+xxx[i], ujy+yyy[i])))< 600000 &&  ujx+xxx[i] <789 && ujx+xxx[i] >10 && ujy+yyy[i] < 630 && ujy+yyy[i]> 10  ){
                     img.setRGB(ujx, ujy,77);
                     bejar(ujx+xxx[i], ujy+yyy[i]);


             }
                 } 
     }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     new Hajra();

 }
}
```

image:

Comment: You could "optimize" it by not using recursion. Consider using a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not optimize tail recursion, so you cannot really 'optimize the recursion'.  You have two options:

**Solution 1 (Easy)**
Run your program with the following flag: `-Xss128m`  This will give 128 megs of memory to your stack - so your recursion has 'more room to breath'.  You can also try other values if your machine has a lot of memory.

**Solution 2 (Harder)**
Modify your algorithm so that its *not* recursive (e.g use a stack).  Every recursive algorithm can be expressed as an iterative solution

Comment: what is this -Xss128m exactly?how do i use it, how do i run in properly, what does it mean?can you elaborate a bit on the subject?

Comment: When you start your java program, say: java -Xss128m <MyProgram>.  This configures the thread stack size per thread in your application to the value you set

Comment: In Eclips or NetBeans how?

Comment: Eclipse: project -> Run As.. -> Run Configurations -> Java Application -> "Arguments" Tab